# Problems with average in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, average

My problem is the following:
I have a list of 12 numbers and I want to do the average of the 10 biggest numbers. I thought about using the MIN function, but I don't know how to use it.

Someone can help me? T

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following formula:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:A12,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))
```

**Explanation:**

- `LARGE(A1:A12,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10})`: gets the 10 largest numbers
- `AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:A12,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))`: gets the average

**OR**

If typing 1,2,3,...,10 takes too long (or in case you want to the average of the largest 50 numbers), you can use the ROW and INDIRECT functions inside the LARGE function like this:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:A12,ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))))
```

After typing the formula in the Formula Bar, use Ctrl+Shift+Enter (not just Enter) to make it an array formula. After entering, it will look like this (wrapped with curly braces):

```
{=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:A12,ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))))}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a large function LARGE(array, k) returning the k-largest entry of the specified array.

The function to get the average of the 10 largest values in the cells A1 to A12 is
=(LARGE(A1:A12,1)+LARGE(A1:A12,2)+...+LARGE(A1:A12,10))/10

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following formula:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,">="&LARGE(A:A,10))
```

[image]